Don't know how to even start this lighting setup
I am trying to pose a photo based on these words from a song: " His trembling hands grabbed the church pew that day. Struggling to stand when they asked him to pray." My thoughts was to silhouette the body and somehow light the hands. Any ideas appreciated. Is my thought process on the right track?

This is not the right forum for your question. This site is for questions with specific, objective answers. If you want to solicit opinions, you will have to post your question elsewhere. I'm sure there are plenty of other sites that could offer ideas - Photo.net as one example.

@osullic Disagreed. This is an example of a Good Subjective question. Photo-SE straddles the objective scientific and subjective artistic sides of the Stack Exchange network.

OP, we can't answer if you're "on the right track" for a subjective question seeking how to photographically convey a concept. But hopefully you'll get some answers with ideas or suggestions about how others might try to approach or pose your concept.

I will probably not answer your first question, but to be a bit more objective I will try to answer this one:

Is my thought process on the right track?

A possible list of thought processes could be asking you the following questions.

What gear do I have?
What space do I have?
What logistics, props, and actors do I have?
What is the mood I want to achieve?
Is this image a part of some other images?
Have I tested the expected result?
What can I do in case the result does not look as great as I intended? What is plan B?

Let me explore a combination of scenarios. The numbers (n) represent a number of the list.
You have continuous light (1) instead of flashes
You could use motion blur to denote trembling hands, and not if you have flashes only.
You have a wide aperture lens (1)
You could focus more on the hands instead of the body, you probably do not need a complex light setup.
You have a lot of space behind the actor (2) and have time to put the desired setup, not only 1/2 hour.
But probably the place has beautiful windows (2), so you want to use them, instead of adding softboxes behind on a dark mood (4)
The character is a thin male (3)
but the hand model is a bit chubby, then ditch illuminating the silhouette of the body, and light only the hand and use DOF.
All the other scenes (5)
have even smoke on the background, then use volumetric light.
Do you have a smoke machine (1)? Can you use incense (3)?
I can imagine a lot of different scenarios.

An important part is 6 and 7
Ask a friend or a member of your family to pose in the kitchen, use a chair instead of a bench, use a woman instead of a man, use a timer or remote shutter if no one can help you, and do experiments. Use a softbox, remove it. Use a slow shutter speed, test the trembling duration, add smoke or not, and change the light positions.
Try before going to the location. The obvious part is that in photography, experience is the most important asset.
And be ready to experiment on location. Your kitchen is probably not as majestic as a cathedral, so be prepared to have a cathedral as a background and adjust your framing accordingly.
For "production value" I would prefer a great shot on location (with some black flags, simply black fabric held by an assistant, and a portable diffused light so the light on the hands is not flat) and use the location. Be prepared to take versions with shallow DOF or a deep one.
